# Permissions error in my application

Tags: android, eclipse, gprs, android-2.2-froyo

I am making an app.I want the app to enable data connection(3G) on its own on android 2.2 and earlier devices.I added the permissions but i get errors "Permission is only granted to system app"..Could someone tell me how to overcome this.THIS HAS TO WORK ON NON_ROOTED PHONES..These are the permissions i added

```
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE    

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

if there's any alternative method its highly welcome

Comment: Which method do you try to use in your code?

Comment: @CharlieCollins-I guessed so..Anyway Is there some way i could enable data from my app

Comment: If you only want that to work on Android 2.2 and earlier phones, it might (not sure). On > 2.2 you cannot use system app permissions (those are reserved for system apps, those shipped with device, or installed on /system by carrier, or on rooted devices). If you're just seeing the error at build time, then disable LINT warnings/errors, you *may* still be able to install and run the APK on older devices?

Comment: To answer your question "is there any way I could enable data from my app" -- I certainly hope not. That would be bad. You can tell the user your app NEEDS data, and take them to the settings dialog where THEY can enable it, or decide not to, but you should not be allowed to control that (and really, you shouldn't be trying to control that, because it can cost the user money and it's an obnoxious thing to try to do, to take over their device settings at that level without their consent).

Comment: Thanks for your help..I get the concern and i know it too...The thing is i am trying to make an app that locates your phone when lost so i do not want to ask the person possessing it to switch on data rather it would be better if i could enable enable data remotely to track the phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem in my last project and the approach we had to end up using, also according to Google's way to handle this issue was to pop up the Setting->Mobile Networks Activity in front of the user, so he could explicitly enable it, not only for requirement reasons but also for Legal Term issues because if your app consumes 3G data making the user spend money without his knowledge, you can get in legal problems...

Regards!

Comment: @Martin-thanks mate.Good to know that i can now focus on something else

Comment: If you think the answer full fill the alternatives you were looking for don't forget to mark it as correct so in the future people take time to answer your questions... Regards!